# flutter pdf view on page tab control

Tags: flutter, fullscreen, pdf-viewer

i have pdf viewer (im using syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package), i want when user tap screen show menu(next page button, previous, go to page ...etc), when tap second time menu hide.
im trying to put pdfviewr inside GestureDetector widget but not work.

```
               Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap:() {
                setState(() {
                  menuBarVisible = !menuBarVisible;
                });
              },
              child: SfPdfViewer.asset(pdfAsset,
                controller: _pdfController,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a Stack() widget and make the GestureDetector() the top-most layer. This might look like the following:

```dart
// ...
Stack(
  children :[
    SfPdfViewer.asset(pdfAsset,
      controller: _pdfController,
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
         setState(() {
           menuBarVisible = !menuBarVisible;
         });
      },
      child: Container()
    ),
  ]
),
// ...
```