# how to scroll pdf in tabview with nestedScrollview - flutter

Tags: flutter, tabbar, tabview, pdfview

I'm using flutter_cached_pdfview can't scroll the pdf in tabview
But scrollable without tabview
Used controller but can't scroll in tabview

Want to scroll pdf in tabview with NestedScroolView

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69535497/flutter-pdf-view-on-page-tab-control#answer-69535787)

```
Stack(
  children :[
    SfPdfViewer.asset(pdfAsset,
      controller: _pdfController,
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
         setState(() {
           menuBarVisible = !menuBarVisible;
         });
      },
      child: Container()
    ),
  ]
),
```